# How can I keep user sessions alive indefinitely?

Tags: node.js, heroku, passport.js, express-session

I have Nodejs, ReactJS and React Native app, MERN app is deployed on Heroku using free dynos. The session automatically times out after some time. I wish to maintain session forever without expiry.

I haven't set any `expiry time`, or `MaxAge` at the time of initialize session:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'thesecret',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
}))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

I expect to maintain session forever in my ReactJS and React Native app. How can I do that on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saving session in mongodb database we can maintain a continuous session in our nodeJS app.

```
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
var store = new MongoDBStore({
uri: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'mySessions'
});

// Catch errors
store.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
app.use(session({
  secret: 'thesecret',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  cookie: {expires: new Date(1586323351000),maxAge:31536000000},
  store: store,
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've configured your [`store`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#store), which means [you're using the default `MemoryStore`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionoptions):

> **Warning** The default server-side session storage, `MemoryStore`, is *purposely* not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.
>
> For a list of stores, see [compatible session stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores).

Heroku dynos [restart frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts), at least once per day, to maintain application and infrastructure health, making in-memory stores impractical even without the previous warning.

You're going to have to pick a new [session store](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores) and configure it. Heroku's filesystem [is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), so please avoid anything that stores its data on the local disk. It probably makes sense to pick one that uses a [data store listed among Heroku's addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores). One of the PostgreSQL backends might be a good choice (you probably already have a [Heroku Postgres database](https://www.heroku.com/postgres)), but there are *lots* of options.